# How to split long word into words?

Tags: php, regex

I have a long word, for example:

```
welcometostackoverflow
```

or

```
betweenparagraphs
```

How to get string or array like this in PHP?

```
Welcome to Stack Overflow
```

or

```
between paragraphs
```

Sample results: 
http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=betweenparagraphs&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBIR

Comment: You can't, not just with regex. You'd need a dictionary file/array to split by, and even then the capitals on Stack and Overflow wouldn't apply, as well as many other issues. This is very hard to do, and I sense an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to split a string like this?

Comment: @JamWaffles thanks for your suggestion.. 
I need to split long word in order to generate unique keyword. 
try to search images at bing for keyword "welcometostackoverflow"

Comment: `try to search images at bing for keyword "welcometostackoverflow"` ... this works because search engines recognize popular keywords and popular search phrases. Otherwise, as @Asif says, there is no way to determine whether a word like "overflow" should be "overflow," "over flow" or "over f low." Search engines generally understand that in this context it is **more likely** to be "overflow" rather than any of the alternatives. But there is no way for them to be 100% sure.

Comment: @jordanmoore : thanks.. how about scrape bing results with curl to get that words? good idea? lol

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty much impossible since your code cannot know where a word ends. Even with a dictionary there would be ambiguous situations.

Comment: try to search images at bing for keyword "welcometostackoverflow"

Comment: If you are a searchengine you will have a big enough dictonary with sutable weights which will help you, to guess which tokes the user wanted to write.

Comment: How big are the chances he has access to something like this? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply.. You can't do that not even with large collection of sample words in an array or a file or something else.

Reasons are:

1. Your input string *as i thought* will not be
   *welcometostackoverflow* everytime.
2. It will cause ambiguous situation in large no. of cases.

   *for example :*
    overflow : it may be `over` or `flow` or `overflow` or `low` ..

Comment: bing and other high level search engines _may_ uses permutation and combination at very high level, together with comparison of _relevant data_ and _last searches_

Comment: offcourse there is very less probability for _impossible_ in programming, but i was just try to elaborate on your bing suggestion.